# Flutter void function does not print a list when called

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this function in Flutter. All it does is take a given JSON file and convert a part of the data into a list and then print the elements of the list.

```
Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('contents.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    final myInts = (data['content_entries'] as List).cast<double>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= myInts.length; ++i){
      print(i);
    }
  }
```

This is how I generate the JSON files:

```
  Future<File> saveToJsonFile(List<Map> contents, String filename) async {
    String encodedLandmarks = jsonEncode(contents);
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path + '/' + filename;
    return await File(appDocPath).writeAsString(encodedLandmarks);
  }
```

When I call the function, this is my output:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset:
/data/user/0/io.flutter.plugins.cameraexample/app_flutter/contents.json
```

The file does exist but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: did you add the file in your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: The file is not in the pubspec.yaml and its dynamically generated..

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using a variable named `myInts` to refer to an object of type `List<double>`?

Comment: It's code from elsewhere. I edited it and forgot to change the variable name.
@jamesdlin Would you be able to help me out with my issue?

Comment: The error refers to `landmarks.json`.  What does that have to do with this code, which refers to `contents.json`?  And if the `.json` file is being dynamically generated, why are you loading it as an asset from the `rootBundle`?

Comment: @jamesdlin The file is generated by a function (check the edits) and saved in the phone. I am trying to load that file from the location it is saved in. I got the idea of using a rootbundle from this link: https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-read-local-json-files-in-flutter/

Comment: @oo92 That link seems to be about loading *static* assets.  For a file you wrote at runtime, you should read it back the same way you wrote it (i.e. with `File(appDocPath).readAsString();`).

Comment: @jamesdlin `A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String`

Comment: @oo92 You've already demonstrated that you know to use `await` to obtain a `T` from a `Future<T>` when you used `writeAsString`.  Using `readAsString` is not any different. [Chirag Kalsariya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72598915/) already gave you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the string from the dynamically generated file as below.

```
File file = File(filePath);
String contents = await file.readAsString();
```

Comment: But that isn't the issue, is it? I'm just not able to print the contents of the file after turning them into lists..

Comment: just print the contents and see, it's in a valid JSON format or not.
Then you can do json.decode and get the expected value from the json.

Comment: Chirag. The output says that it can't load the asset.

Comment: Please go to the that location in the emulator manually and check file is exist or not. if yes then what is the content in it.

Comment: I'm running it on my phone and not able to find even the location..

Comment: Might be this will help you,
https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/26/how-to-list-files-folder-from-internal-or-sd-card-storage-in-flutter-app/

Comment: @oo92 You never even reach the code that attempts to print the contents because you fail to load the JSON file with `rootBundle.loadString`, as indicated by the error message.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your pubspec.yaml file
- Find the `flutter` > `assets` section
- Add the filename

Assuming the file is in the `assets` folder
e.g.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/contents.json
```

Comment: Its not. The file is in `/data/user/0/io.flutter.plugins.cameraexample/app_flutter/`.

Comment: Also, adding this file's path to pubspec.yaml doesn't make sense because the code generates the json file..